# how to judge and analyze the convergence region under Runge's phenomenon

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Under the background of polynomial interpolation, Runge's phenomenon is a problem of oscillation at the edges of an interval that occurs when using polynomial interpolation with polynomials of high degree over a set of equispaced interpolation points.
[![Runge's phenomenon]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJuie.jpg)

While the error near the ends of the [-1, 1] would divergence as the number of interpolation points goes to infinity, does a region around the center of [-1, 1] upon which the error of the interpolated polynomial converges exists?

How to solve this question? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Take the error formula for Lagrange interpolation and some geometric bound on the derivative sequence. You should get convergence for segments inside the radius of convergence (of the geometric bound, or of the power series of the function), which is $r=\frac15$ for the Runge function $\frac1{1+25x^2}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Good idea, thanks. By the way, beside derivative sequence as you pointed out, from the view of complex plane, the outermost curve in the complex plane inside which the function is analytic also shows the region upon which equispaced interpolants will converge.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Let's take cos(x) as the function to be interpolated. In theory, it converges in [-1,1] as the derivative sequence is bounded. However, when we do it in numerical way, the error near the ends of [-1,1] still divergent as the number of dots increase. For this situation，how to analyze it?